# Where's my Triskaidekaphile hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

On SO this morning I won my 13th silver medal.

But don't you think that anyone who gets a badge in any category that brings the total up to 13 should get a Triskaidekaphile  hat? (Means, if I really need to say, a love of the number 13).

I was half expecting *something* to happen.

Comment: You earn, not win badges and hats

Comment: Minus twelve? Is there no justice in the world?

Comment: well done! +1 for your accomplishments!

Comment: +1 so that the Q is only -13. Almost as good as a hat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no hat for winning 13 badges, but have no fear: there will be all-new hats next year.